# Spanning a range of colors to a text in HTML

Tags: html, reactjs, colors, next.js

I am comparatively new to HTML & I recently came across a website (YT video) which made a beautiful range of colors on the button. Link to the website: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPaLnMw2i_0

I was wondering if these ranges of colors used can be implemented to some text in HTML. Could anyone help me out with this?
[Range of colors used on the tab Button (This is done using React & Next.js)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wD9c.png)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline CSS and its linear-gradient function.

Read:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()

Example:

```html
<p style="
    background:linear-gradient(to left, blue, pink);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 10em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    margin: 10rem auto;
">Learn More</p>
```